# R fuzzy sets - Cannot plot tuple of fuzzy multisets

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to implement [this example](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/eControlHTML/Fuzzy/Fuzzy1.html) using R's fuzzy set capabilities.  Code:

```
sets_options("universe", seq(from = -200, to = 200, by = 1))
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fuzzy Variables
variables <-
  set (
    temp = fuzzy_variable(cold   = fuzzy_trapezoid(corners=c(-101, -100, 40, 70)),
                          ok     = fuzzy_triangular(corners=c(40,70,100)),
                          hot    = fuzzy_trapezoid(corners=c(70, 100, 200, 201))),
    ctrl = fuzzy_variable(small  = fuzzy_triangular(corners=c(-50,0,50)),
                          med    = fuzzy_triangular(corners=c(0, 50, 100)),
                          large  = fuzzy_triangular(corners=c(50, 100, 150)))
  )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fuzzy Rules
rules <-
  set(
    fuzzy_rule(temp %is% cold, ctrl %is% large),
    fuzzy_rule(temp %is% ok,   ctrl %is% med),
    fuzzy_rule(temp %is% hot,  ctrl %is% small)
  )

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set up Fuzzy System
system <- fuzzy_system(variables, rules)
print(system)
plot(system)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example
# If the measured temperature is 80 degrees, what's the control effort?
fi <- fuzzy_inference(system, list(temp=80))
## plot resulting fuzzy set
plot(fi)
## defuzzify
gset_defuzzify(fi, "centroid")

## reset universe
sets_options("universe", NULL)
```

When I run it however, I get two errors:

```
> plot(system)
Error in lines.tuple(as.tuple(x), ...) : 
  Cannot plot tuple of fuzzy multisets.
> fi <- fuzzy_inference(system, list(temp=80))
Error in rep.int(0, len - length(ret)) : invalid 'times' value
```

I'm a bit stumped.  Did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047870/fuzzy-system-in-r) which looks like a similar problem but I can't see typos in above.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.  Using R v3.2.4 on windows in case that matters.

Answer (score 2):

This was an environment problem.  Reset the RStudio environment & it worked.  Leaving Q&A here in case anyone sees the same thing.

Comment: No need. You can delete.